# Writing-mode: vertical-rl is not working when website is open in face book app

Tags: html, css

I have the following button in my website. This is vertical button and it is working in browser. But when the website is opened in Facebook app example, if I share my webpage link in Facebook and people are clicking that page & web page is opened in Facebook app then this button is not vertically aligned. How can I solve this:-

```
<div class="my-class">MJI Offer</div>

.my-class{
    background-color: black;
    color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20%;
    padding: 7px;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;

}
```

Please help. If vertical-rtl is not working what are the alternative solution. I can't use **transform:rotate(90deg)** because when I do this one then the button have a gap from the side of the website.

Comment: Can you please put your code in snippet?

Comment: i already put it in the question

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try this!
If you are seeing the gaps you must try changing the CSS.

HTML Code

```
<div class="button-container">
<input type="button" value="Rotated text" id="rotate" />
```

CSS Code

```
#rotate{
  vertical-align:top;
    transform:rotate(7deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera */}

.button-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 40px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    width: 400px;   
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```